# SLIM php Angularjs CORS

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, cors, slim

I'm using SLIM framework as backend and Angularjs as frontend.Normal GET and POST API's is working fine.Whenever i pass the headers in GET or POST method it is throwing 404 error.I used the .htaccess file for CORS.

```
    RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, authorization"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Check your server's error log. Which requests are generating a 404 response?

Comment: Chances are, your server is not responding correctly to the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. Let me see if I can find a catch-all solution

Comment: ok. I have been trying this for more than a week. I can't get it

Comment: Have you looked at this ~ https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/enable-cors.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome, you can open the network tab within the Developer Tools to view the failed request. If it's related to CORS, then it will tell you why it failed.

A 404 error usually means that the endpoint cannot be found, so check carefully that the Angular code is requesting the URL that you think it should be.

Comment: The 404 is probably because nothing is responding to the pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests correctly. The Slim framework should be configured to handle them

Comment: Slim does handle OPTIONS automatically for you.